# Worker service process stops for no apparent reason when using async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, service-worker

I've set up a really simple work service project, with just a single worker (for now). Here's the complete code for the ExecuteAsync method:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  try
  {
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
      var engine = new CrawlerEngine(_logger);
      try
      {
        await engine.CrawlAsync(stoppingToken);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
      }
      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }
    _logger.LogInformation("Worker stopping at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
  }
}
```

As you can see it's fairly simple, just an infinite loop until cancellation and the only real logic in there is all wrapped inside the CrawlerEngine.

Here's the catch, if I run the service it'll run for maybe a couple of minutes and then just exit. It'll not log "Worker stopping" nor an exception, it just plain stops the entire process.

I tried changing all the async code inside CrawlAsync, so it's completely synchronous. This removes the problem and leaves me puzzled.

Every Async method I have inside CrawlAsync returns either Task or Task and is awaited.

So I'm figuring maybe some of the async code throws an exception that isn't caught by the try-catch, however to the best of my knowledge the exception should "bubble up" and be caught as long as you're using await.

I even added an AppDomain.UnhandledException handler, that catches nothing as well.

Do you have any ideas what the heck is going on here?

EDIT: Just for clarification I'm asking whether there's any hidden details to async, that can cause it to crash an entire process with no amount of try-catch being able to see it?

**EDIT 2: Seems what's crashing my process is WebClient.DownloadStringAsTaskAsync as well as HttpClient.GetStringAsync. Whenever I use either one, my process just exits at some point. Using a synchronous method for downloading string doesn't cause this.**

Comment: I don't believe you won't get much feedback here as we can't see what you changed to get it to work. The logic in your execute method is basic and there is nothing anyone will glean from that. And just a side-note: you should pass in your stopping token to `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));`

Comment: One more thing: I would back out and start over. Start by taking out `engine.CrawlAsync(stoppingToken);`. Then slowly add things back a couple of lines at a time. Maybe make it synchronous to the point where it works, then start changing things back to async and run it as a hybrid until it breaks.

Comment: Are the calls all the way up the call stack async?

Comment: The calls all the way up the stack are async yes.
Good call on the stoppingToken to Delay, I'll add that.
If I remove engine.CrawlAsync the worker runs infinitely just fine, so it's definitely something in there that goes awry. 
However the main question here is really: How can the application just stop without any errors etc. when running async, when it doesn't do so without async?

Comment: Any clues in the Windows event log?

Comment: sellotape: I'm running Linux, so no event log :-)

BUT I did find out something, following Andy's approach of slowly making it async again. The culprit seems to be WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync (deep in my async stack). As soon as I change that to a synchronous call, the problem goes away.

Comment: `hidden details to async, that can cause it to crash an entire process with no amount of try-catch being able to see it?` - `async void` could do that, but there's nothing else with `async` that could do that.
I'd recommend using `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient` for sure.

Comment: Stephen: That was also my understanding, and the reason why I always use async Task. Thanks for the tip about HttpClient, I'll look into that.

Comment: What compiler and versions are you using. Can you reproduce a [mcve]?

Comment: Sadly I can't, I tried simply looping infinitely with the async Http call, but it never died. So it's some combination of events that lead to it. However when I keep everything but that call synchronous it still happens, whereas if I leave the rest of the project async and just change the HTTP call to synchronous, it works fine.

As for compiler and version I'm using .Net SDK 5.0.202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was exiting the process: a StackOverflowException.

This explains the lack of logging etc.
I've solved it by changing a recursive method (which called HttpClient.GetStringAsync) to a for loop.

Why it didn't throw StackOverflow when using the non-async variant of GetString is still beyond me though.